# Perl: Best way to use counterbalancing across conditions

Tags: perl

I have a script with two conditions (C1 and C2). Every time a user log in, I want this user to be assigned to one of those two conditions using a strict counterbalancing (not random assignment), such that User1(U1) is assigned to C1, U2 to C2, U3 to C1, U4 to C2, etc.

What is the simplest way to do this?

Right now, I was thinking of doing this:

```
my $cond;
my $out_cfile = "cfile.txt"; #intial value printed in the file is 1
open(CFILE, "+<", $out_cfile) or die "cannot open $out_cfile";
flock(CFILE, 2);
my $cdata = <CFILE>;
my $last = (substr $cdata,-1,1); #get the latest printed value
if ($last == 1) {$cond = 1; print CFILE "2";}
if ($last == 2) {$cond = 2; print CFILE "1";}
close(CFILE);

print "my condition is: $cond";
```

Is there a way to do this without having to open and print to an output file?

Comment: Does this need to be thread safe?

Comment: yes, ideally, it should.

Comment: You could write up a single-threaded server that gives out the conditions. This might be cheaper at medium to high loads. However, that would require one extra process.

Comment: What is your issue with a file?

Comment: @ikegami: I hate having programs with multiple attached files. But basically, I am just looking for the simplest way to do the counterbalancing, within the fewest number of lines of code. As such, using threads is too complex for what I am looking for, I'd rather use a file. I thought there would be a practical and simple way to do that. People are clever on this board.

Comment: To be clever, we needed to know what the problem is we're trying to solve. You hadn't specified that, which is why I asked.

Comment: You're making it heard to help you. Will there be multiple simultaneous accessors that will need mutex, or won't there?

Comment: Yes, multiple simultaneous accessors. Sorry for not having been clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't understand the pain of creating a file in the `/tmp` directory or whereever if it doesn't already exist, but you could use [`memcached`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Cache%3a%3aMemcached) instead.

```
use Cache::Memcached qw( );

my $memd = Cache::Memcached->new({
   server    => [ '127.0.0.1:11211' ],
   namespace => 'app_name:',
});

my $val = $memd->incr('counter');
if ($val % 2) {
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

`incr` increments and fetches atomically to avoid race conditions (so it's safe like your code).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a tied hash, but if you want thread safe you'll need to implement some form of mutex, maybe a semaphore.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to use a [`lock`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlthrtut.html#Controlling-access%3a-lock%28%29) (**Warning:** Untested, but something like this should work):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use threads::shared;
use Thread::Queue;

my $num_users_logged_in :shared = 1;

my $num_watcher_threads = 1; #it may make sense to make this larger, maybe not. 

my @users = (); #populate array of users that are logging in.

my $queue = Thread::Queue->new;

$queue->enqueue(@users);

my @threads = ();

foreach(1..$num_watcher_threads)
{
  push @threads, threads->create(\&log_in);
}

# NOTE: If you ever want this program to stop, 
# then you'll have to enqueue some undefs (one for each thread).

# Waiting for each of the threads to finish.
# If you don't want to do this, then detach() instead
$_->join() foreach(@threads);

#Do anything else that you want after all of the threads are done.

sub log_in
{
  #Threads will block until it grabs an undef in the queue
  while(my $user = $queue->dequeue)
  {
    #Do whatever you need to do before locking the variable.
    {
      lock $num_users_logged_in;
      #Other threads will block until we're done with this block of code.

      #Assign conditions based upon the parity of $num_users_logged_in
      #And do whatever else you need for that particular user

      $num_users_logged_in++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I like your solution, but it is too complex for what I was looking for. As mentioned in my question, I was looking for a simple solution. But your script is a nice start to implement threads for several solutions. I will try playing around with it. I did not downvote, I up voted you.